# Code stops executing after a method call

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random

I am trying to set up a method for placing products into my store, and the code does not execute after I call a method.  It does not throw any errors, it simply does not execute and I cannot figure out why.

Heres where AddProduct is called

```
void Start()
{
    try
    {
        db = GameObject.Find("Database").GetComponent<Database>();
        dm = GameObject.Find("DispensaryManager").GetComponent<DispensaryManager>();
        AddProduct();
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException)
    {
        print("Database is null");
    }
}
```

The code stops running after the 5th line:

```
public void AddProduct()
{ // This method is called one time during the Start() method of its gameobject
    List<StoreObjectReference> jars = db.GetProducts(StoreObjectReference.productType.jar); // this is not null
    GameObject jar = Instantiate(jars[3].gameObject_); // successfully instantiates
    jar.AddComponent<Jar>();
    jar.GetComponent<Jar>().product = new StorageJar(jar);
    print("This prints"); // This prints
    ProductPosition jarPosition = dm.dispensary.Storage_cs[0].GetRandomStorageLocation(); // Storage_cs[0] is not null
    print("This doesnt print"); // Never reached
    jar.transform.position = jarPosition.transform.position; // Never reached
}
```

And heres the GetRandomStorageLocation()

```
public ProductPosition GetRandomStorageLocation()
{ // Does not throw any errors
    print("Getting product position"); // This prints
    return storageShelves[0].positions[0]; // This does exist, I am only hardcoding the two indexes for testing purposes
}
```

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43Wjl.png) of the console after the code is executed

And here is ProductPosition

```
public class ProductPosition : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Product product; // the product stored here
    public Vector3 positon; // position for products stored here
}
```

Comment: you sure your debug console is not discarding the errors? Top right of the console, you can set to only print message or warning or error. You could try to do something like Debug.Log(storageShelves == null); Debug.Log(storageShelves[0].positions == null);

Comment: Go to Console tab in Unity Editor then take a screenshot of it and post the image in your question.

Comment: I am sure that is not the case, I also have it set to pause the editor when an error appears and that never happens

Comment: Show us the code that calls AddProduct(). Do exceptions bubble up to a try/catch block? Also is ProductPosition a reference type or a value type?

Comment: @WesleyHendon You have eight lines "where the code stops running". Which is it?

Comment: @EdPlunkett There are 2 print statements, the first one prints and the second print statement does not.  Ill edit the question to make it more clear where this is

Comment: Change `catch (NullReferenceException)` to catch `Exception` - let's see if there is some other exception that is escaping the flow.  Also, instead of `return storageShelves[0].positions[0];` assign to variable and then return variable - let's see if accessing arrays/collections has some funky in it.  Post results.

Comment: How and where do you initialize `storageShelves` and the `positions` variable inside it ? I suggest you do what Everts said.

Comment: Did anyone find the solution to this? My Selenium code also stops midway after calling a method.